# loop wait for function complete node.js

Tags: node.js

** i am trying to download videos with loop. but loop do not wait for function complete.

```
for (var i = 0; i < linkLength; i++) {

download ();  

}
```

Is there a way to make loop wait for the download.
edit 2. Solved . Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your download code?

Comment: who knows  , where is my mistake help me?

Comment: Now what is the issue?

Comment: What are you doing with your code? it's not proper code

Comment: i know it is for testing only . i solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js nature is `asynchronous` that's why you are getting this issue.

You need to make it's nature as `synchronous` with the help of `callback` or `promises`.

I recommend using [eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachSeries) of [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module which provides relevant way to resolve this issue

**Example**

```
async.eachSeries(linkLength, function (item, callback) {
download(callback);
};

function download (callback) {
//After completing your tasks call callback here
    callback();
}
```